# Android App ForceCloses on Starting of a new activity

Tags: android, manifest, forceclose

I am new to android development and I have been having issues with Force Close on new Android Activity Pages.

My Structure is like this:

Main Page -> Menu Page (Works Fine) -> New Game Screen(force closes)

Call to the Activity:

```
    public void btnNewGame_Click(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewGameScreen.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}
```

Manifest

```
        <activity  android:name=".NewGameScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/eLVGameList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:background="@null" android:layout_height="0dip">

    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

NewGameScreenActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loadgame);


   ExpandableListView epView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.eLVGameList);
   ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = new GameListAdapter();
   epView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Errors:

```
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloandroid/com.example.helloandroid.NewGameScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ExpandableListActivity.onContentChanged(ExpandableListActivity.java:222)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.example.helloandroid.NewGameScreen.onCreate(NewGameScreen.java:22)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-05 20:16:57.375: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your activity extend ListActivity and need a Listview with the right Id to work. @Deepak as the right id for your listview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your ExpandableListView id with this

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

and if your class extends Activity then change it to

```
public class className extends ListActivity
```

and you can get your ExpandableListView by calling the method

```
ExpandableListView listView = getListView();
```

Comment: It didn't help. :(
I renamed the id as list and also changed my reference inside to: R.id.list, didn't help.

Exact same error, I don't think it is the id naming issue. For some reason I have some reference wrong that my NewGameScreen is not able to read my ExpandableListview properly.

Comment: if your class `extends Activity` then change it to `public class className extends ListActivity`.
and you can get your ListView by calling the method `ListView lv = getListView();`

Comment: Actually I apologize, I messed up. I had changed my id to "@id:List" not what you wrote,
So, I changed the id to what you suggested and now I am unable to find the view by id. 

    ExpandableListView epView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


Could you also suggest how do I reference that listview here?

Comment: you can get your ListView by calling the method ListView lv = getListView();

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, you just forgot to insert the NewGameScreen Activity's Entry in the AndroidManiFest.xml Write down following line in your AndroidManifest.xml file before the  tag.

```
<activity android:name=".NewGameScreen"></activity>
```

And also important thing that your NewGameScreen class must `extends` `Activity`

Comment: I already have .NewGameScreen in the Manifest...

And my NewGameScreen can't extend Activity (Or I think it can't) because I am using an expandableListview. So i found out that I have to extend ExpandableListActivity.

Comment: well if it desnt not extends Activity, then no need of declaring it in AndroidManifest.xml as Activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the id of your ListView as      `android:id="@android:id/list"` , if you are extending LIstActivity. Then you can get your ListView handler from getLIstView();
If you are extending Activity, then you can give any other id to your ListView and get it using findViewbyId()
From the LOgCat trace, it looks like you are using ListActivity.