# onListItemClick not called on Listfragment

Tags: android

Hello I have a problem with the onListItemClick Method on a ListFragment.

I have an activity that holds 2 ListFragments. The first one is a sub navigation and the second one shows some content. The sub nafigation werks perfectly fine and the onListItemClick event is invoked when clicked on a list item. But for the second ListFragment, nothing happens. The method is not invoked.

So far I also tried to replace the Listfragment with a Standard Fragment and set the setOnItemClickListener manually. But it is not fired when I click on a list entry. I also tried to test it with a different Listener (e.g onLongItemClick), but nothing happened either.

These are the settings for my listview.

```
   <ListView    
            android:id                  ="@+id/mylistview"
            android:layout_width        ="match_parent"
            android:layout_height       ="match_parent"
            android:divider             ="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight       ="10dp"
            android:listSelector        ="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint      ="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Note, that i replaced the id with the standard "@android:id/list" when using a ListFragment.

Does anybody know what goes wrong here ? Can it be that the other ListFragments gets all the onListItemClick calls and prevents this one from being fired ?

Here is the adapter that is attached to the list:

```
setListAdapter(new CustomRatingBarListAdapter(mListEntries,
            getActivity(), R.layout.content_view_list_layout,
            new int[] { R.id.list_item_text1 }, new String[] { TEXT});
```

Comment: check my [older](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9577954/1250370) post if this help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the error. It was something complete different. 
In fact I had a rating bar as a list item and even tough it did not cover the whole list item it somehow got all the click events.

Changing the visibility to GONE for now solved the problem. So the problem was here the layout of a single list item and not the adapter.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an item in your layout that can steal input from other components like a RatingBar, that component needs to be defined as not focusable, so it won't grab events.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your adapter's list items (rows) (the *.xml file on layout/ folder) setting:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Or if you are injecting them programmatically, code:

```
yourChildView.setFocusable(false);
```

Do this with all the UI components that could take focus such as Button, RatingBar, EditText, ToggleButton inside the View that constitutes the list item (row) etc.

Comment: In my concrete situation it hasn't helped to only set the `android:focusable` attribute on my `myRowLayout.xml`. I'd to also set it programmatically - god knows why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get your ListView by calling this method `getActivity()`.

If I am right then use this `getListView();` insted of `getActivity()`.

Comment: Since 2 ListFragments are active at the same time maybe it has something to do with the context. But changing the context to getListView() does not help. Since both Fragments are attached to the same activity, do I have to tell the activity how to handle the clicks ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnTouchListener()` instead to other components in my list row  did the trick for me. Hope that help.